# Adapter classes implemetation and create an instance of MyMouseAdapter

Tags: java, awt

I was trying to learn adapter class. I came across a code from the book I am   reading from. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class AdapterDemo extends Applet
{
    public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

This is not the complete code. The problem is the compiler does not recognize MyMouseAdapter inside `init()` but the book says it would . I am reading an old book on java 2. What's the reason for my problem and whats its solution.

Comment: Java 2 by Herbert Schildt

Comment: i did import java.awt.*

Comment: the book says adapters are implemented by awt

Comment: Adapter that is implemented by AWT is MouseAdapter

Comment: thats what i am asking about bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand the context fully but you can use it like this:

```
public class AdapterDemo extends Applet
{

  class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
     [...]
  }

  public void init()
  {
      addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
  }
}
```

But for short testing and understanding, i would recommend you to use the MouseAdapter like this:

```
  myButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
```

Whatever the books says, i would prefer to read more about the `MouseAdapter` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll called your adapter `MyMouseAdapter` - so unless you've created your own class with this name then the compiler won't know what it is.

Try changing `MyMouseAdapter` to `MouseAdapter`

Comment: I think the point of the demo is to do something with an overridden `MouseAdapter` class (`MyMouseAdapter`) rather than just using the default one.

Comment: @DavidWallace  - I agree - the OP now has code that compiles but doesn't react to mouse clicks. The next step is for him to add the code to the MouseAdapter to make it do something meaningful.